# svn: any way to combine checkins of separate partial checkouts?

Tags: svn, commit

Let's say I have a huge SVN repository (don't we all), and I am working on two libraries in separate checkout directories.

Is there a way to atomically commit both of them in a single checkin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are truly separate checkouts, then you can't.  But you can checkout your huge repo sparsely, getting only the two libraries you are interested in.  Then you can commit your changes to both at once because they will be in a single working tree.